# fix blurred vml background images in internet explorer (raphael)

Tags: internet-explorer, raphael, vector-graphics, vml

I am using Raphael to create a vector shape and fill it with a background image.

The image is blurred in internet explorer.
You can see this using ie 8 on the following url https://justplay.thefa.com/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who finds this...I got to the solution to my particular problem after a day of trial and error. I read a remark someone made about another aspect of using vml which I remember having issues with in the flash days with fonts.

The problem arises when you are not using integers for your x/y points in a path. The line below gives an example of the last box as it was.

```
r.path('M4.5,24.875L175.5,17.95L175.5,136.598L4.5,132.125Z')
```

This was resolved by removing the sub pixel positioning which was causing ie to try and anti-alias the image across pixels

```
r.path('M4,25L175,18L175,136L4,132Z')
```

And we now have much nicer images

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Raphael 2.0](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/2.0)? I think it's still in beta stage, but I found that it's got improved VML capabilities.

Also be sure to test browser behavior with an uncompressed version of Raphael, as minified versions seem to have bugs. Instead, I've used [Packer by Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), which gave me a compressed and bug free version of the lib.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I found the solution after a day of trial and error which I will add below.